# Displaying records from selected date only

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, calendar

I have a search button that when pressed displays the `Calendar` control. The reason for the `Calendar` control is that I have a data list which is connected to a sql data source and returns values such as `Date`.
I want to be able to select a date that it *only shows the records on that specific date*.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Calendar1.Visible = true;
}

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE DateColumn = '" + Calendar1.Value + '";
```

This is your query. Now execute this query.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1])); // here reader[0] means first column in Table.
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay! Yes iv tried this but when I select a date, nothing fires. I have my date in the format: ie 01/14/2014. There are 2 records with this date but nothing happens when I select this date. I feel I could be close though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ControlParameter` for this on your `SqlDataSource`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.ASPX

By default the propertyname will use the `Calendar.SelectedDate`, but you can explicitly set if you prefer for clarity.

Your code should resemble something like below:

```
<asp:sqldatasource
          id="SqlDataSource1"
          runat="server"
          connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
          selectcommand="SELECT Dates FROM Dates WHERE Date = @Date">
          <selectparameters>
              <asp:controlparameter name="Date" controlid="Calendar1" propertyname="SelectedDate"/>
          </selectparameters>
      </asp:sqldatasource>
```

Comment: Would I use the Calendar1_SelectionChanged? whenever I  change the date nothing is happening and it is not displaying the results even though I have the above code..

Comment: It's a property not an event, selecteddate. It's worth having a read of the above link. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

At what point do you need help?

1. If you are confused how to fetch records on that particular date, simply pass the selected date from the calender control as a `parameter` to a `SQL Stored Procedure` and execute it to store the returned data into a `DataTable`. Now you can use that `DataTable` in the code-behind as you wish.
2. If you are having problem with the Calender Control, you can try with `Ajax CalenderExtender` which is very easy to use.

   ```
   <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalenderDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" PopupButtonID="btnSearch" Format="yyyy-MM-dd">
                               </asp:CalendarExtender>
   ```

Now clicking the `btnSearch` button will open the Calender. You can access the selected date from code-behind as follows

```
DateTime date = CalenderDate_CalendarExtender.SelectedDate;
```

You need to add the following to make the calender extender work

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

And This

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan. Where would I include the register assembly. Is this in the web config file?

Comment: You need to add it below your Page Directive in .aspx page. It should come before any HTML or other design mark-ups. If you are using Visual Studio 2010 or above, it should automatically detect the assembly. Otherwise, you have to externally download and add the assembly to your Project Bin folder to make things work.